# How to setup ODBC server using ml-gradle?

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-dhf

What parameters should I add to gradle.properties to automate ODBC server setup?
I could not find in the reference site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any properties to create one automatically, so just add a file to src/main/ml-config/servers with the ODBC server config in it.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation, currently am doing in that manner:)

Comment: Here is an actual example: https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/blob/master/examples/sample-project/src/main/ml-config/servers/odbc-server.json